# Zend framework 2 routing required query parameters not working

Tags: php, zend-framework, routes, zend-framework2

I'm working on zf2 to make one of my routes only accessible when a query string parameter is passed. Otherwise, it will not. I've added a filter on the route section but when accessing the page without the query parameter, it is still going thru.

```
'router' => array(
    'routes' => array(
        'show_post' => array(
            'type' => 'segment',
            'options' => array(
                'route' => '[/]show/post/:filter',
                'constraints' => array(
                    'filter' => '[a-zA-Z0-9-.]*',
                ),
                'defaults' => array(
                    'controller' => 'blog_controller',
                    'action' => 'show'
                )
            ),
        ),
    ),
),
```

`http://example.com/show/post/?postId=1235` = This should work

`http://example.com/show/post?postId=1235` = This should work

`http://example.com/show/post/` = This should not work

`http://example.com/show/post` = This should not work

Comment: You can't (or shouldn't) route on query parameters in ZF2. You'll have to check for these in your controller, or use a different URL structure (e.g. `/show/post/postid=1235/`)

Answer (score 0):

The way you currently have this setup you would have to structure your url like this

`http://example.com/show/post/anything?postId=1235`

I think what you are wanting is to structure your route like this

```
'route' => '[/]show/post',
```

Not sure what you are trying to accomplish with `[/]` before show though, you are making that dash optional there?

I would write it like this

```
'route' => '/show/post[/:filter]',
```

This way you can structure your urls like this

`http://example.com/show/post/anything?postId=1235`

or

`http://example.com/show/post?postId=1235`

Then in your action you can access those parameters like this

```
$filter = $this->params('filter');
$post_id = $this->params()->fromQuery('post_id');
```

or just

```
$post_id = $this->params()->fromQuery('post_id');
```

***************UPDATE***************

It looks like zf2 used to include what you are trying to do and removed it because of security reasons.

http://framework.zend.com/security/advisory/ZF2013-01

Comment: The reason why I added a filter on the routing is to redirect to an error page should no query string parameters be passed. Can it be directly be done on the `module.config.php` instead of having a method on the controller that validates if an query string is passed or not?

Comment: best practices are you should still load default data with params or make a set of default params you add on if none exist. Otherwise if you are expecting something like `post_id` on that url then make that a parameter of the route like this `'route' => '/show/post/:post_id',` then you are guaranteeing that you will get that parameter and if it is not there they will go to your `404` page

Comment: Exactly. Just as I stated that this page requires a query parameter. Should it not exist then it will redirect to an error page. But the problem is that, base on the code I provided above, should a query parameter exist or not, it always redirect to the controller's method which should not.

Comment: so what is the required parameter you are thinking of?

Comment: any query parameter will do for now. As long as there is a query parameter.

Answer (score 0):

> Don't try to bend ZF2 standard classes to your way. Instead write your own route class, a decorator to the segment route, which will do exactly as you please:

```
<?php
namespace YourApp\Mvc\Router\Http;

use Zend\Mvc\Router\Http\Segment;
use use Zend\Mvc\Router\Exception;
use Zend\Stdlib\RequestInterface as Request;

class QueryStringRequired extends Segment
{
    public static function factory($options = [])
    {
        if (!empty($options['string'])) {
            throw new Exception\InvalidArgumentException('string parameter missing');
        }

        $object = parent::factory($options);
        $this->options['string'] = $options['string'];

        return $object;
    }

    public function match(Request $request, $pathOffset = null, array $options = [])
    {
        $match = parent::match($request, $pathOffset, $options);
        if (null === $match) {
            // no match, bail early
            return null;
        }

        $uri  = $request->getUri();
        $path = $uri->getPath();

        if (strpos($path, $this->options['string']) === null) {
            // query string parametr not found in the url
            // no match
            return null;
        }

        // no query strings parameters found
        // return the match
        return $match;
    }
}
```

This solution is very easy to unit test as well, it does not validate any OOP principles and is reusable.

Your new route definition would look like this now:

```
// route definition

'router' => array(
    'routes' => array(
        'show_post' => array(
            'type' => YourApp\Mvc\Router\Http\QueryStringRequired::class,
            'options' => array(
                'string' => '?postId=',
                'route'  => '[/]show/post/:filter',
                'constraints' => array(
                    'filter' => '[a-zA-Z0-9-.]*',
                ),
                'defaults' => array(
                    'controller' => 'blog_controller',
                    'action' => 'show'
                )
            ),
        ),
    ),
),
```